# Wallet issues with bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

i am new to this bitcoin universe and signed up on a website called genesis mining, a form of cloud mining. it asked for my bitcoin wallet address but can't find it no where in the bitcoin wallet app or the program i downloaded, does anyone whom have the app or software know where to go to find your wallet address? I search everywhere on both programs to no luck at all.

Comment: what is the name of wallet applications you are using?

Comment: i am using bitcoin core and the app as well but can't for the life of me find out where is my wallet infomation

Comment: In Bitcoin Core, go to the Receive tab and click Request Payment.  Make sure to back up your wallet.dat file.  As for "the app", please clarify which one; there are lots of wallet apps for Bitcoin.